# In CakePHP, why would $this->params['form'] be empty if I've just posted a form?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

**Using CakePHP 1.3**, I post a form which correctly fills in `$this->data`. According to [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/964/form), it seems like `$this->params['form']` should be populated with some information as well, but it's simply an empty array. **Is there a particular reason for that?**

The form is built using the Form Helper, as follows...

#### Some relevant code:

```
$default_form_create_options = array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label'=>false, 
        'div'=>false
    )
); 

echo $form->create('Preappform', $default_form_create_options);
// --- snip, a bunch of form elements created via $form->input()
echo $form->end(array('label'=>'Send This Form &raquo;', 'class'=>'submit-button', 'escape'=>false));
```

I know that the form data is available in `$this->data`, so maybe this is just a documentation/curiosity issue. If so... my bad.

Comment: It is pretty hard to say without any relevant supporting code.

Comment: I would recommend posting your code and also doing a var_dump($this->params);

Comment: Well, when I have time I'll be sure to condense the rather large, existing form into a smaller test case, to show what's happening. I did dump $this->params, which has an empty array in 'form'.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using $this->params['form'] rather than $this->data?

Comment: @Travis: Because the documentation mentioned that 'form' contained data submitted via the form. I'm currently using 'data', but wondering what 'form' is actually for, I guess.

Comment: I think the params attribute has some additional stuff in it generally, including named or other GET params.  $this->data holds the form data that was submitted by post.  Give that a shot -- it's it's what I generally use, as it's shorter (which may be it's primary reason for existing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for giggles try `$this->params['data']`.  I don't know why but for some reason it shows form data in there for me.

The documentation has conflicting data as you can see here http://book.cakephp.org/view/972/data.  I am guessing that if you use the *FormHelper* it will show up in `$this->data` and if you don't use the *FormHelper* it will show up in `$this->params['form']`.

Notice if you use *FormHelper* the name of the element will be `data['Model']['element_name']` and if you just create the form manually you can name it 'element_name'.  By doing the later I believe it throws it into the `params['form']` instead of the `$this->data`.

Comment: If this is the case, then it explains why I'm hating the CakePHP Documentation lately.

Comment: Yup, `$_POST = $this->params['form'];` except when using FormHelper. You should be using the FormHelper in your application to make things easier, so using `$this->data` in the controller is the way to go. However, if people are POSTing to your controller action from an external source (ie. you are providing a web service),  you can separate concerns by checking `$this->params['form']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same while working with CakePHP 1.3. Later I solved the issue by using the $this->params['data']. But I have some questions, I'm a newbie to cakephp and using the manual as my reference, it seems that the manual is not at all updated, while searching about this issue, I found out that it was working well in earlier versions and after 1.2, it is not at all there in Cakephp. Is there any CakePHP experts to clarify this stuff ?

Comment: On StackOverflow it's a good tone to put into your post only answer to original question. To clarify something for yourself, you better put it in comments (to your or original post) or ask independent question

Comment: Also I just noticed that OP is old and have accepted answer. And since no one on SO looks for new question in answers, it's extremely unlikely someone will help you in this thread. "Ask new question" button is in upper right corner of the page

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily related to Cake, but the answer to the problem when I had it: if you're including a file upload in your POST, double-check that the file you're uploading isn't larger than the limit specified in your `php.ini` file.