# updating a cakephp model field through jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i'm trying to update a the field of a cakePHP model through a jquery request.

eventhough the ajax call is a success , the model isn't updated on the database .

```
<?php $Url = Router::url(array('controller'=>'coupons','action'=>'update_statut'),true); ?>

  $.post('<?php echo $Url ?>', { id: id},function(data) 
      { alert("sucess");
    }).error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

on the controller's side here's the action :

```
function update_statut(){
      Configure::write('debug', 0);
      $this->autoRender = false;
       if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->Coupon->id= $this->params['form']['id'];
            $this->Coupon->saveField('statut','terminé');
           }
```

i even hardcoded the id in the action to make sure it fits with my table row.

any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might wanna check out if you u've done

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

might be the condition

Comment: yess apearently the condition on the handler was screwing up ... i totally forgot to import the component , thanks man .. silly me

Answer (score 0):

i not a pro of cakephp but can you try to replace

```
$this->Coupon->id = $this->params['form']['id'];
```

by

```
$this->Coupon->id = $this->params['data']['id'];
```

?

you could find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771169/in-cakephp-why-would-this-paramsform-be-empty-if-ive-just-posted-a-form).

Comment: didn't work , i don't think there's something wrong with this part as is tried  to hard code $this->Coupon->id = 1; (wich corresponds to the row id in my table)  and still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

firstble try to work with $.get like this :

```
<?php $Url = Router::url(array('controller'=>'coupons','action'=>'update_statut'),true); ?>

  $.get('<?php echo $Url ?>'+'/'+id, {},function(data) { 
          alert("sucess");
       });
```

and in function update_statut add the parameter id like this one:

```
function update_statut($id=null){
      Configure::write('debug', 0);
      $this->autoRender = false;
       if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->Coupon->id= $id;
            $this->Coupon->saveField('statut','terminé');
}
```